# how do I add click listener to listview items?

Tags: android, listview

This is my listview. I am able to add items to it dynamically. But how do I show the item in a toast when I click it??

```
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    Addbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    GetValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final List<String> ListElementsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(ListElements));
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Scanner.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ListElementsArrayList);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    Addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListElementsArrayList.add(GetValue.getText().toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set an OnItemClickListener on the ListView. For example,

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Get the selected item text from ListView
        String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        // Display the selected item in a Toast
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

See https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-listview-item-click.html

Answer (score 0):

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //TODO find a better way to handle show and get what items are selected
                if (!isItemSelected[i])
                    view.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                else view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000);
                isItemSelected[i] = !isItemSelected[i];
            }
        });
```

See above example from my code your looking for "setOnItemClickListener"